# IWDG not stopping on debug when CAN Receive interrupt triggered

Tags: stm32, can, debugging

I'm having a significant problem debugging my board with CAN traffic. Whenever the debugger is paused, and a CAN message is received, the independent watchdog is being reset. As far as I can tell, I'm disabling that peripheral on debug correctly, but anytime I set a breakpoint, the IWDG is resetting the MCU. If my board does NOT receive any CAN messages, everything works as expected.

#### Relevant Information

- MCU: STM32F091VB
- Development Environment: IAR Embedded Workbench 9.30
- Debug Probe: STLink/V2

Below is my code for disabling peripherals for debugging:

```
//Halt Interrupts on Debug stop
__HAL_RCC_DBGMCU_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_FREEZE_IWDG_DBGMCU();
__HAL_FREEZE_WWDG_DBGMCU();
__HAL_FREEZE_TIM1_DBGMCU();
__HAL_FREEZE_TIM2_DBGMCU();
__HAL_FREEZE_TIM3_DBGMCU();
__HAL_FREEZE_TIM16_DBGMCU();
__HAL_FREEZE_CAN_DBGMCU();
```

Disabling the watchdog entirely appeared to work, but pausing in the debugger only allows me to debug the CAN interrupt i.e. I'm stuck infinitely in that interrupt, even if there are no CAN messages being received.

Comment: Isn't `__HAL_FREEZE_CAN_DBGMCU();` supposed to disable CAN interrupts when stopped in debug mode? Maybe adding `__HAL_CAN_DBG_FREEZE(__HANDLE__, __NEWSTATE__)` would prevent the CAN module from running? or settting the CAN_MCR DBF flag some other way.

Comment: @M Virts I would have thought it would disable CAN interrupts too, but it appears that that is not the case. I tried your suggestion of setting the CAN_MCR_DBF flag, but that did not work.

Comment: Wouldn't "beeing stuck for ever in an ISR" point you towards a "wrongly/incompletly" implemented ISR? I guess you could add a "Clear ISR Flag" in there - then the ISR should not get triggered twice/for ever.

Comment: It's a long shot but you could check for an upgrade to your STLink/V2 firmware (https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link007.html). May also be worth manually verifying that your build target and libraries are for the exact chip you're using, IAR workbench probably does this automatically.

Comment: Please don't cross post on multiple SO sites. Duplicate at SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932138/iwdg-not-stopping-on-debug-when-can-receive-interrupt-triggered. Your question is on-topic on both sites, but since it seems like the debugger might potentially be the culprit, SO is more suitable. (There's a couple of IAR experts following the IAR tag on SO, for example.)

Comment: Thanks, I honestly wasn't sure which was more appropriate. Should I delete this post then?